# What libraries can I use for syntax highlighting popular languages in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, grammar, textmate

I'm interested in creating a code editor app for Android in C# (using [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)). Obviously, one of the necessities for any great code editor is syntax highlighting for a wide range of popular languages. I don't want to write custom tokenizers for all of these languages myself, so I'm looking for a library that already has grammars for them.

From my time browsing the [VSCode editor source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), I know that there are many predefined grammar files for certain languages, in `.tmLanguage` (TextMate-style) or `.cson` (Atom-style) format. For example, [here](https://github.com/atom?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language-&type=&language=) are a bunch of grammars maintained by Atom, and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage) is the official C# grammar maintained by the .NET Foundation.

I initially sought a .NET library that would parse these files and allow me to match them against expressions, but AFAICS none exists. Something like [vscode-textmate](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-textmate) or [textpow](https://github.com/grosser/textpow) would be just what I'm looking for, but those are not written in .NET.

Can anyone point me to a library that would help me with this purpose? Also, would it be a good idea to use a [.NET JavaScript engine](https://rushfrisby.com/which-net-javascript-engine-is-the-fastest/) to execute functions from the above libraries if I can't find any? Normally I wouldn't hesitate to use an engine, but I'm afraid delays of a few hundred ms would not be acceptable for syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is an Android specific question, so you should make it clear. GitHub has its Android client open source which uses a control, https://github.com/pockethub/PocketHub. You might check what exactly they do in Java and then translate that to C# and Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one of my current projects I did a research of available syntax parsers. One of them was ANTLR, and here is an article on how to use it from C#: https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-antlr-in-csharp/

It has a very large (over 100) collection of pre-build grammars for different languages: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

ANTLR is Java based, so I guess it will not be an issue to get it working on Android.